# Insert form data directly to PugiXML doccument

Tags: c++, xml, visual-studio-2010, pugixml

I'm trying to insert data from a form in VC++ 2010 using pugiXML.

The issue is that whenever I try to enter the data, I get this error:

```
Error   1   error C2664: 'pugi::xml_node::set_value' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'System::String ^' to 'const pugi::char_t *'
```

The code I'm using to insert the data is this:

```
descr.append_child().set_value(eClass->Text);
```

The documentation states that these functions accept string parameters, so I'm not sure why I'm getting an "expected char_t" error.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be trying to pass a

```
System::String
```

to pugixml. This string is not a char *, but a CLR string. You need to use

```
PtrToStringChars()
```

to access the actual content and pin the string.

Take a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d1ae6tz5.aspx) on how to pass its contents to a function that accepts char * or wchar_t *.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try convert the string to char* ?

`descr.append_child().set_value(eClass->Text.c_str());`